# How would I concat several videos of different sizes into a single video?

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation, core-media

I have several video files of different sizes, same aspect ratio though, on a device Camera roll, I’m looking to create of them a single video, scaling up the smaller video files to fit into the whole “video frame size”.

I’m looking into AV Foundation, and am not sure if I need to go to a lower level of Core Media or should I be looking at the AV Foundation AVAssetWriter. It doesn’t seem like AVAssetWriter accepts AVComposition.

Which approach should I be taking for this kind of video related app?

Answer (score 0):

AVMutableComposition is what you want.  AVAssetWriter can write the file to disk since AVComposition is a subclass of AVAsset.